# WebXR - "dom-overlay" optional feature on Android 11

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, webxr

I'm playing around with WebXR and implemented a dom-overlay with some controls for the AR-Experience.

It all *worked fine on Android 10*, but with Android 11 the overlay is not transparent anymore.

I have made no changes except of course update to Android 11.
On a different phone, still with Android 10, it also still works.

```js
    const options = {
       optionalFeatures: ['dom-overlay'],
       domOverlay: { root: document.getElementById('arControls') } 
    };


    navigator.xr
      .requestSession('immersive-ar', options)
      .then((session) => {
        session.isImmersive = true;
        this.createSession(session);
      })
```

The Chrome Version I'm using is 85.0.4182.101.

How can I fix it? Is this a known bug?
Are there any alternatives?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in Chrome 86. Download Chrome beta from the play store if you can't wait.